# Query packages installed after action

Tags: centos, centos-7, yum, rpm

I'm trying to find out which packages have been installed by a script on CentOS7 which uses yum, so I can later download as rpms to install it on a similar machine offline. 
I've come up with some solutions, but they require 'greping' around on output, I was wondering if there's a standard way to query for packages installed in certain period of time. 
 My solutions are:

1. With `yum history`: first clear itwith `new`, and then make an `addon-info` with all transactions to see everything that happened (or save a `saved_tx` file) and then grep around
2. grep directly on `/var/log/yum.log`
3. With `rpm -qa --last`, then grep the ones installed today

Other approaches to this are also welcome.(Note: the script is a very complex ansible playbook, is not an option to just scrap the source code)

Comment: I don't use yum, so I don't know. If I were doing this in Debian/apt, I would dump a list of all installed packages before running your script (using dpkg) and then another one right after it ran and do a diff. Looks like `rpm -qa > before.txt` then run your script,then `rpm -qa > after.txt` then `diff before.txt after.txt` should do that as long as nobody else installs things before you run it. If you want to GUI it, try `meld before.txt after.txt`.